# Try with resource why cannot modify resource

Tags: java, java-8, try-catch, variable-assignment, try-with-resources

I found a try with resources example that doesn't compile when I try to set the value of the reference scan to null

```
try(Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    String s = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(s);
    scan = null;
}
```

I ask what's the rule behind this compilation error , I did some search on the net but i didn't find a rule that explain it 
Thanks for any explanation : =)

Comment: Probably because otherwise the `try` would need to do something like save a separate reference to the resource just in case the user attempted to reassign it, but that's kind of silly. It would also lead to confusing code where it isn't entirely clear by the end of a block if a resource is going to be automatically closed or not. If the resource reference is reassigned, should the previous object still be closed? What about the new object that the reference points to?

Comment: Lets say you can assign other value to resource declared in `try(..){` like `try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(...)){pw.write("something"); .. pw = PrintWriter(...); }`. In this situation you have two `PrintWriter` instances. For which one try-with-resources should generate code responsible for closing it? If you pick only one (regardless which) one of them will not have code responsible for closing it which is counter-productive and against the idea of try-with-resources. That is why arguments used in it must be final or effectively final.

Comment: try with resources would try to close the scan, which in this case would mean to call `close()` on a null pointer. So its a good thing that you cannot do that. This is one of the reasons for try with resources treating the resources as final variables for the block

Comment: @LeedMx there is always a `null` check before closing a `try-with-resource` variable, so it's not a problem. Actually, you can initialise a variable with `null`, and the block will be executed smoothly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's by design. You can't reassign a `final` variable.

> ### [14.20.3. try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3)
>
> A variable declared in a resource specification is **implicitly declared `final`** if it is not explicitly declared `final` (§4.12.4).

Comment: It may be also worth mentioning that try-with-resources doesn't need to *declare* variables. It can also accept already existing variables, even if they are non-final, for instance `PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("path/to/file"); try(pw){ pw.write("foo"); }`. But it also requires that those variables will not be reassigned (even outside of try-with-resource block) - they need to be *effectively final* .